# why doesnt this Javascript work when mixed with php?

Tags: php, javascript, html

im trying to grab search items from twitter via PHP curl, process and update them every second. In this simple version im just trying to refresh the search results for "bieber" every second. i have combined php with the javascript and im guessing its the reason things don't work...but I need to understand why. In my understanding Apache sends only html back to the browser...so why is there a problem with the innerHTML specification:
Here's the script

```
<head>
<script type = 'text/javascript'>


function refresh(){
document.getElementById('target').innerHTML= <?

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=bieber&rpp=100');

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$var = curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($var, true);



for($i = 0; $i<500; $i++){
if(empty($obj['results'][$i]['text'])){
 echo $i;
 break;
    }
echo $obj['results'][$i]['text']."<br/>";
}

?>
;
var refresher = setTimeout("refresh()",1000);

}

</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="refresh()">
<div>
<span> stuff </span>
<div id ='target'>
</div>


<div id= 'rest'>
The Rest of the page that does not refresh
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I know there's AJAX and JQuery etc but let's mention them only after we've explained to me why there's a problem with this code and why what im doing is not possible without those technologies.

Thanks!

Comment: change <? to <?php and add quotation marks before the <?php an after ?>

Comment: Wrap your PHP output in quotes: `.innerHTML = "<? php stuff ?>";`

Comment: tried that...didn't fix it...:(

Comment: what does the PHP error log report, if any? EDIT, also, what's the rendered script, could you post it please?

Comment: Stop searching 'Beiber', that *might* fix it.

Comment: @jnpcl It's slightly more complicated than that as the PHP output will need to be properly escaped so that it doesn't accidentally terminate the JavaScript string literal.

Comment: @algorithmicCoder: Also, refresh is a reserved keyword. Use a different name for the function. like funcRefresh or something

Comment: @jnpcl: "add quotes" is bad advice. What happens if there' a quote inside the retrieved text? Instead, pass the whole block of returned text through `json_encode()` and boom, instant valid javascript, regardless of how many/few quotes there are inside it.

Comment: @algorithmicCoder: Your problem is definitely the PHP script. Run the PHP script separately and see if it returns the expected values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at your HTML source that is returned to the browser after the PHP executes on the server side:

```
<head>
<script type = 'text/javascript'>


function refresh(){
document.getElementById('topTen').innerHTML= Never sewn my daughters as mesmerized as right now while they watch the Justin Bieber movie....sheeeeesh<br/>I just took &quot;A 12 year old and 16 year old co...&quot; and got: 4: We shouldn't, we couldn't, we wouldn't...We did.! Try it: http://bit.ly/mksZGq<br/>@justinbieber +..., is not knowing all his songs, not being a fan is to have all existing products of Justin Bieber +...<br/>Bieber set to meet Sept 11 victim: Justin Bieber is set to meet a 9/11 victim's daughter after a request from US... http://bit.ly/lbP6w6<br/>@xxoxxSasixxoxx hey how many pics am i limited to for the bieber vÃ­deo? :D hahahaha<br/>@MissCarrusel es todo por culpa de la boda real, Justin Bieber y la Gaga...<br/>Bieber set to meet Sept 11 victim: Justin Bieber is set to meet a 9/11 victim's daughter after a request from US... http://bit.ly/lbP6w6<br/>I just took &quot;Your a popular girl at school and Justin Bieber is a n...&quot; and got: Part 2 &quot;a thousand times yes&quot;! Try it: http://bit.ly/jHROiv<br/>ngga sama sama haters kita kwkw @FyaanaR Jenni belieber ya? RT @arikakautsar: Gara&quot; tautan justin bieber hub ane sama jenni jadi gimana git<br/>ei meninas vi agora o trote de vcs no twitcam adorei danÃ§ando o
justin bieber (@LuanaSoeira live on http://twitcam.com/4ve65)<br/>Lol ahahahahahahaha Poppy ?? Bieber ?? Really ?? Lol ai it must be that hair @poppyismyname (TV)5<br/>@0rfeo_ Yehuu aÃ§Ä±ldÄ± lÃ¦ :D balkona Ã§Ä±kan justin bieber hayranÄ± gbi olcam. ordan atcam mention baÄŸÄ±rarak ama..<br/>Dios mio hasta en la sopa RT @tusabiasque Justin Bieber acapara el 3% de los recursos de todo twitter. http://bit.ly/b2bUX0<br/>RT @evenpro: Para los fanÃ¡ticos de Justin Bieber, esta es la cuenta del Club de Fans en Venezuela ---&gt; @JBieberVenezla<br/>Describe your perfect date? â€” Being with Bieber. http://4ms.me/mIbZkr<br/>wtf bieber fans? i won't follow you -_- #GoAway<br/>I find that a side effect of bieber fever is the need to scream a LOT. #itsabelieberthing<br/>RT @evenpro: Para los fanÃ¡ticos de Justin Bieber, esta es la cuenta del Club de Fans en Venezuela ---&gt; @JBieberVenezla<br/>Untung La Justin Bieber Bole Bole Men Kiss2 Ngan EX Aku
*Jeelluuzz ~ http://fb.me/MqNfHaR4<br/>RT @AlexandreMedina: &quot;Prezado senhor Justin Bieber, informamos que o resutado da anÃ¡lise da mancha vermelha em seu pÃªnis era sÃ³ baton. Lamentamos a amputaÃ§Ã£o&quot;<br/>RT @tusabiasque: Justin Bieber acapara el 3% de los recursos de todo twitter. http://bit.ly/b2bUX0 /Colaborando con la causa Cc: @walterdva<br/>Bieberohhecknophobia: fear of accidentally listening to a Justin Bieber song and not having the ability to rip your freakin ears off<br/>Watch Justin Bieber's movie and tell me he's not talented. He's overrated as a popstar and underrated as a musician.<br/>I just took &quot;(Part 1-11) &quot;Just Because I'm his sister, Doesn't mean I can't meet him.&quot; (...&quot; and got: Part 7:l! Try it: http://bit.ly/kJcbdI<br/>I like inspiring stories. RT @AmazonVideo...Justin Bieber: Never Say Never available at Amazon Instant Video. http://amzn.to/m4mfdA<br/>@JBIndonesiaa dr bieber<br/>I don't know how I got so obsessed but I love Justin Bieber. http://tumblr.com/xkv2i6zju5<br/>I just took &quot;SEASON ONE: ALL PARTS: The plane crash caused you to be stuck on ...&quot; and got: Part 12-HAWAII!!!!! Try it: http://bit.ly/jwlkWP<br/>RT @justinbieber: its here. #NSNweekend #NeverSayNeverDVD - http://itunes.apple.com/us/movie/justin-bieber-never-say-never/id425624519<br/>Dear Justin Bieber........... NEVER! sincerely, i will never say never.<br/>R E T W E E T if you have a serious case of Bieber Fever, and dont want the cure :) [i auto follow back]<br/>RT @evenpro: Para los fanÃ¡ticos de Justin Bieber, esta es la cuenta del Club de Fans en Venezuela ---&gt; @JBieberVenezla<br/>Justin Bieber Never Say Never ! :) Watching it all day. &lt;3 IloveyouJustinDrewBieber! (((((:<br/>I just took &quot;Raped by my own brother every single day. What happens wh...&quot; and got: Part 33-Happy anniversary!! Try it: http://bit.ly/kiZco4<br/>I just took &quot;Your a bad teen, you sneak out, and skip school. Y...&quot; and got: Part 6 : Gomez. ( Kinda Rated R )! Try it: http://bit.ly/jTvysb<br/>@vangiemartelle Eh kanina ka pa. hahaha. I texted youuu. :))) Sabi ko you've been BIEBER-fied. haha<br/>OMB . i have bieber fever ! ;) &lt;3<br/>RT @OmgSoEpic_: That awkward moment when you realize Flo Rida is Florida Will. I. Am is William , B.o.B is Bob &amp; Justin Bieber is .....WELL..SEXY (; #OSE<br/>TELL ME WHAT IS HAPPENING TO JUSTIN BIEBER?!?!?!?<br/>Did you guys see DC choreographer @DevinMW &amp; #PhunkPhenomenon last night on #ABDC? It was Bieber night! Clip here: http://on.mtv.com/kdOUjE<br/>RT @RachelKaitlyn: Hahahahahahaha this gay guy goes &quot;omg are you talking about justin bieber...? The only thing good about him is his hair&quot;<br/>I liked a @YouTube video http://youtu.be/kspPE9E1yGM?a Justin Bieber vs. Slipknot - Psychosocial Baby<br/>RT @lyekmh: Come watch @awirafael, Justin Bieber of Malaysia, this Sunday for Sunday Afternoon Jam  at Morning Rocket, Cheras<br/>Congratulation for that news!! RT @GuadalupeHyre32: @gabriel_ysturiz LoooooooL :), that's awesome, Justin Bieber (cont) http://tl.gd/aehlt6<br/>@JBIndonesiaa dr bieber<br/>Nowplaying : justin bieber - one less lonely girl :)<br/>Photo:  http://tumblr.com/xuj2i6z47a<br/>GET LAID NOW!! CLICK HERE: http://ow.ly/3Bjc9 #Sex Miley Cyrus Taylor Swift Kim Kardashian Lady Gaga Justin Bieber<br/>Unwell Bieber tells off airport crowd at Manila departure - Manila Bulletin Error Reported, We are sorry for that !<br/>Send this round to support Justin Bieber . We Love you Justin Bieber â™¥â™¥â™¥â™¥â™¥â™¥â™¥â™¥â™¥â™¥â™¥â€¦ â€” done â™¥ http://4ms.me/ieZiLQ<br/>Haha! &quot;@TheQuoteWhore: â˜‘ Hitler (Done) â˜‘ Saddam Hussein (Done) â˜‘ Osama Bin Laden (Done) â˜ Justin Bieber (Today) â˜ Rebecca Black (Friday)<br/>http://nemkutya.com/2011/05/problem-bieber/ xDDD<br/>ben adÄ±mÄ±n justin bieber a benzedgÄ±nÄ± sanmÄ±yorum ya butun bÄ±eber cÄ±lar benÄ± takÄ±p edÄ±yor :D<br/>TELL ME WHAT IS HAPPENING TO JUSTIN BIEBER?<br/>Dicen que un #viernes13 naciÃ³ un tal justin bieber y se predijo que al terminar la primera dÃ©cada del 2000 nos harÃ­a la vida una mierda<br/>WYR meet Justin Bieber or Jasmine V? â€” Justin Bieber http://4ms.me/jFgsxo<br/>- ;Oh how the girl sings beautifully! 
- ;Mom, this is Justin Bieber! : D
hehe<br/>Redbox has the justin bieber movie now @acd2doom :)<br/>May 13: Donald Trump Gets a Book Deal and Justin Bieber Has Obama's Back - msnbc.com Error Reported, We are sorry for that !<br/>KKKKKKKK , Justin Bieber chegou em Hong Kong rodeado de 20 seguranÃ§as e foi recepcioado por 7 fÃ£ns, #idontbelieveit!<br/>I &lt;3 Justin Bieber<br/>RT @justinbieber: its here. #NSNweekend #NeverSayNeverDVD - http://itunes.apple.com/us/movie/justin-bieber-never-say-never/id425624519<br/>:D soo I didnt get to buy daah Justin Bieber Movie yet.! But will soon.! RT if youu have it already.!<br/>I just took &quot;Your a bad teen, you sneak out, and skip school. Your mom ...&quot; and got: Part 7 : Ouch, That Hurt.! Try it: http://bit.ly/iB8P1d<br/>mn hele tijdlijn is vol over justin bieber.<br/>a chi piace justin bieber ??? 
se dovete fare insulti o cose varie non rispondete<br/>mi futuro marido serÃ  JUSTIN BIEBER! (@sgomez349 live on http://twitcam.com/4venx)<br/>RT if you love Justin Drew Bieber .<br/>Every little boy has a haircut like Justin Bieber -_- but most of them just look like chili bowls<br/>I just took &quot;You and your 3 bestfriends went to Bahamas on a vacation. One day you were...&quot; and got: Part 2 &lt;3! Try it: http://bit.ly/k0bwxW<br/>I just took &quot;You get signed to the same label as Justin Bieber and hes posing for pict...&quot; and got: Part 24 &lt;3! Try it: http://bit.ly/mqGUyj<br/>ahahaRT @arinurcahya: Gue kira hayley beneran lg dgrin justin bieber (Â¬_ Â¬&quot;) RT @indrawwrr: #nowplaying Justin Bieber - One Less Lonely Girl<br/>Lady Gaga, Justin Bieber, And Others Are Entertainers And Nothing ...: facebook justin bieberâ€¦ http://goo.gl/6HLE<br/>MNT ..BIEBER FACTS In french : )<br/>I just took &quot;A 12 year old and 16 year old could never be dating until y...&quot; and got: 3: HEEELLLLOOOO BAHAMAS!! Try it: http://bit.ly/mksZGq<br/>RT @ProjectOLLG: #thingsgirlswantboystodo Make us feel like One Less Lonely Girl like Justin Bieber.Tell us we're amazing just the way we are like Bruno Mars<br/>RT @evenpro: Para los fanÃ¡ticos de Justin Bieber, esta es la cuenta del Club de Fans en Venezuela ---&gt; @JBieberVenezla<br/>RT @evenpro: Para los fanÃ¡ticos de Justin Bieber, esta es la cuenta del Club de Fans en Venezuela ---&gt; @JBieberVenezla<br/>I just took &quot;A 12 year old and 16 year old could never be dating until you me...&quot; and got: 8: Juvie For Bestie! Try it: http://bit.ly/mlzEew<br/>Twitter.com Justin Bieber: Twitter Com Justin Bieber 6 - justin bieber first step foreverâ€¦ http://goo.gl/6HLE<br/>Want to see. RT @AmazonVideo...Justin Bieber: Never Say Never available at Amazon Instant Video. http://amzn.to/m4mfdA<br/>Sel y Justin Bieber viven un tÃ³rrido romance que algunos creen que podrÃ­a ser eterno, pero Sel sabe que tiene que pisar tierra. #BreathBySEL<br/>Get lost twitter over capcity my ass
Peace&lt;3&amp;bieber<br/>baby baby baby ohh!!! RT @Feris_Othman: You sound like Justin Bieber.<br/>Dr bieber RT @JBIndonesiaa: #ajl1 r-d-e-b-e-i-r-b (skype cody)<br/>RT @justinbieber: its here. #NSNweekend #NeverSayNeverDVD - http://itunes.apple.com/us/movie/justin-bieber-never-say-never/id425624519<br/>Justin Bieber Official Site: Justin Bieber Official Site 11 - justin bieber poster never sayâ€¦ http://goo.gl/6HLE<br/>RT @Nooahx: RT @dominiquebiebz: i speak bieberish my blood is purple i live in bieber's world justin bieber is my hero and i'm a proud belieberâ™¥â™¥<br/>OH MY GOD, FACE IT YOUR SURNAME IS NOT BIEBER AND YOU ARE NOT GOING TO MARRY HIM. Arg.<br/>&quot;Justin Bieber, lo mÃ¡s perfecto que he visto.&quot; #JAJANOMAMEN!<br/>@Stepzzz wat je hebt justin bieber gezien nho :p<br/>Music Videos Of Justin Bieber: Music Videos Of Justin Bieber 9 - justin bieber test your superfanâ€¦ http://goo.gl/6HLE<br/>@TheBieberHelp oh okay JUSTIN DREW BIEBER ;) &lt;3<br/>Feeling sick calls for a pedicure and polish change. My color of choice... Justin Bieber purple. îŒ­<br/>@justinbieber http://news.getmusicasia.com/2011/05/11/justin-bieber-live-in-philippines/
~CharisseJustinBieber love you!!!<br/>I LOVE JUSTIN BIEBER I LOVE JUSTIN BIEBER I LOVE JUSTIN BIEBER I LOVE JUSTIN BIEBER<br/>So my son tells me he's gonna get me  a Justin Bieber cake for my Birthday<br/>I liked a @YouTube video http://youtu.be/mnx6kD6A7rQ?a Ryan Beatty - U Smile Justin Bieber Cover<br/>SELENA GOMEZ CONFESSA QUE COMENTÃRIOS DE FÃƒS DE JUSTIN BIEBER A MACHUCAM! http://bit.ly/kpalnR<br/>MY BIEBER FEVER IS COMING BACK!!!!!!:):):)<br/>100;
var refresher = setTimeout("refresh()",1000);

}

</script>
</head>
```

Basically, because the PHP code is executed before the page is returned to the page, the content that is fetched is effectively a static string in the javascript code, not something that will ever change.

What you need to do is add a separate PHP script that just fetches the new content and then have your Javascript  make an AJAX request to periodically fetch the new version of the content from the second PHP script.

[This tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-javascript.php) describes how to do the javascript end of the request. The PHP end will just be a script that performs your curl requests and returns the output:

```
<?php
// fetchContent.php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=bieber&rpp=100');

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

print curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);

exit;
```

Comment: 1) but this 'static string' is not even printed in the apprpriate div 'target' 2) i think your point is more so that setTimeout will not work as expected...i can accept that! but how about pt. 1

Comment: (point 1) The other problem in your original code is that the HTML string that the PHP is printing in your Javascript block isn't quoted and contains new-lines, resulting in invalid Javascript code. You can see this if you view the source of your HTML page.

Comment: Thanks for the Links!...so would the Javascript event be onLoad? and is the setTimeout method what to use to periodically get the content

Comment: awesome!...works like a charm...now Ill move on to actually doing something constructive with the data...thanks alot!....btw the print json_decode($var, true); statement doesn't work it just prints out "Array" also sizeOf(json_decode($var, true); does not give the size of the returned array instead it just gives 11...weird

Comment: @algo: json returns a PHP data structure. In this case it's an array, so you have to use `print_r()`. sizeOf an array returns the number of elements in it, not the number of characters stored inside.

Comment: thanks for the print_r point....but the size of the "array" or some component of it certainly isn't always 11 regardless of what i search for...so still not sure about whats going on there

Answer (score 3):

Comment boxes are too short for this, so i'm writing it out as an answer.

here's how your script executes

1. User hits the script URL
2. Webserver fires up the PHP script
3. Inside the script, CURL fetches the Twitter text, and inserts it into the page's javascript section.
4. The generated page is sent to the client
5. The php script exits, the webserver finishes sending the page to the user, and shuts down the connection
6. The user's browser loads up the page, displays it
7. The 'refresh' function is called
8. The refresh function takes the text that was inserted at step #3 and re-inserts it into the page
9. goto #7

Notice that in steps 7-9 that PHP and the webserver are *NOT* used again, so the twitter text is NOT changed.

What you've done is the equivalent of writing something on a piece of paper, handing it to someone, and telling them to go over there read what's on the paper every 5 minutes.

What you need to do is tell that person to phone home instead, so your server can fetch another chunk of twitter text and read it out to the person over the phone. And when they're done reading the text, they should phone in again for another set of text.

Answer (score 0):

You can have php write out JavaScript but not the other way around because php is server side and executes first.

Comment: the php IS writing into the javascript

Comment: why is it a problem if it executes first?...isnt this good?...When I view source of the page I can actually see that the php has been rendered and innerHTML is being set to what I want....it just doesnt display in the appropriate div...

Comment: @algo: Because the PHP executes *ONCE* on the server. It fetches some text from Twitter and embeds it in your page. That page is sent to the browser, and then PHP is done. Calling 'refresh' via javascript doesn't reexecute the PHP. It just re-inserts the very same text that's embedded in the page